# Detecting interactions between Canvas objects

Tags: java, android, android-studio, game-development

In my current prototype I have a fixed grid of rectangles I draw on the canvas in a loop, and a red square "gamePiece" which can be dragged around the screen by a player's finger (screenshot below). **My goal is to make it so that the player square can interact with the grey squares**, but I'm not sure how to detect interactions between canvas objects. How can this be accomplished?

The relevant chunks of my code are below, but please let me know if there is anything else I can provide to help. I don't expect anyone to make this for me, but if someone could point me towards good resources I would appreciate it a lot!!

[image]

**Code**

GamePiece (Red Square)

```
public class GamePiece implements GameObject {

    private Rect rectangle;
    private int color;

    public GamePiece(Rect rectangle, int color) {
        this.rectangle = rectangle;
        this.color = color;
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setColor(color);
        canvas.drawRect(rectangle, paint);
    }

    @Override
    public void update() {

    }

    public void update(Point point) {
        //ltrb
        rectangle.set(point.x - rectangle.width()/2, point.y - rectangle.height()/2, point.x + rectangle.width()/2, point.y + rectangle.height()/2);
    }
}
```

GameTile (Individual Gray Squares)

```
public class GameTile implements GameObject{

    private RectF rectangle;
    private int color;

    public static int tilesPerRow = 10;
    final public static int TILE_SIZE = (PolyGoneUtils.getScreenWidth() - (40 + 20 * tilesPerRow)) / tilesPerRow;

    public GameTile(RectF rectangle, int color) {
        this.rectangle = rectangle;
        this.color = color;
    }


    @Override
    public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setColor(color);
        canvas.drawRoundRect(rectangle, 10, 10, paint);
    }

    @Override
    public void update() {

    }

    @Override
    public void update(Point point) {
        rectangle.set(point.x - rectangle.width()/2, point.y - rectangle.height()/2, point.x + rectangle.width()/2, point.y + rectangle.height()/2);
    }
}
```

GameBoard (makes the grid of GameTiles)

```
public class GameBoard extends View {


    private static final int originX = 30;
    private static final int originY = 400;
    private static final int tileSize = GameTile.TILE_SIZE;
    
    public GameBoard(Context context) {
        super(context);

    }

    
    public static void makeGameBoard(Canvas canvas) {
        
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
                GameTile gameTile = new GameTile(new RectF(originX + i * tileSize + (20 * i),
                        originY + j * tileSize + (20 * j),
                        originX + (i + 1) * tileSize + (20 * i),
                        originY + (j + 1) * tileSize + (20 * j)), Color.DKGRAY);
                gameTile.draw(canvas);
            }

        //System.out.println("Squared Dimensions of the tiles are: " + tileSize);
        }
    }
}
```

And Finally here is my GameView

```
public class GameView extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {
    private MainThread thread;
    Context context;

    private GamePiece gamePiece;
    private Point piecePoint;

    public GameView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        this.context = context;

        getHolder().addCallback(this);
        thread = new MainThread(getHolder(), this);
        setFocusable(true);
        
        gamePiece = new GamePiece(new Rect(300, 300, 384, 384), Color.rgb(255, 0, 0));
        piecePoint = new Point(342, 342);
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {

    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(@NonNull SurfaceHolder holder) {
        thread = new MainThread(getHolder(), this);

        thread.setRunning(true);
        thread.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(@NonNull SurfaceHolder holder) {
        boolean retry;
        retry = true;
        while(retry) {
            try {
                thread.setRunning(false);
                thread.join();
            } catch (Exception e) {e.printStackTrace();}
            retry = false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: //player pressing down
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: //player moving their finger
                piecePoint.set((int)event.getX(), (int)event.getY() - 100);
        }

        return true;
        //return super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }

    public void update() {
        gamePiece.update(piecePoint);
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.draw(canvas);

        canvas.drawColor(Color.parseColor("#201E36"));

        GameBoard.makeGameBoard(canvas); // Drawing GameBoard Grid

        gamePiece.draw(canvas);
    }
}
```

Comment: "I'm not sure how to detect interactions between canvas objects." – You just have to do the math, basically. `Canvas` isn't really tracking any of your objects; it's simply recording values for draw routines. If everything is going to be rectangles, then it's not terribly difficult to determine if two intersect, or the distance between centers, etc. The `Rect` and `RectF` classes might help a tiny bit with some basic arithmetic, but ultimately, you'll have to handle tracking and checking all of that.

Comment: @MikeM. Thanks for the reply Mike. That is kind of what I was thinking. I could take the center point of my player rectangle and check if it falls within the coordinates of any of the gameboard tiles. My question is, how can I get the coordinates of my tiles? is it possible to store it for each one as I am creating them, like in the `makeGameBoard` method?
RectF has the intersects method, but my gameTiles are made dynamically so I dont have them stored in variables (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/RectF).

Comment: "how can I get the coordinates of my tiles?" – That's the `RectF` that you pass in `GameTile`'s constructor. That will be in the same coordinate system as the touch events that you're handling in `GameView`. "my gameTiles are made dynamically so I dont have them stored in variables" – I'm not sure why you've gone that route, but you really should store those in an array or list field somewhere, instead of creating and discarding them each time `onDraw()` runs, 'cause that method needs to run as quickly as possible.

Comment: @MikeM. I really appreciate your help, and the way you answer questions with the "quotes" is super helpful. I've been diving head first into this project so I'll try to think about the problem in the way you described.

One followup question about the last thing you said. I was under the impression that drawing has to take place in GameView draw or onDraw. Can it be done somewhere else to free up resources each loop? Again, I appreciate you taking the time to talk with me!

Comment: No problem. These things can get convoluted, and I don't always express myself exactly as I mean to, so hopefully the quotes help to keep each point separate, and in context. Anyhoo, it's not the drawing that's the issue there; you can move the drawing stuff into as many separate methods as you like. It's that you're creating all 100 of those `GameTile`s and `RectF`s every time `makeGameBoard()` is called, which happens each time `onDraw()` runs, which can happen many, many times a second. If that `new GameTile(new RectF(…` line was directly inside `onDraw()`, you'd probably get a warning.

Comment: Ohhh I think I get what you're saying. If I were JUST drawing the rectangles from a saved array of their dimensions then it would be okay, but I'm not. I **am calculating** those values each time I run the loop. Or at least that's what you mean!!

Comment: Yeah, the arithmetic also doesn't need to be redone each time, but the big resource drain there is actually the `new GameTile()` and `new RectF()`. Object instantiation is a little more expensive than math with primitives, but every little bit helps, of course.

Comment: try with this,https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Games/Techniques/2D_collision_detection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following @Mike M.'s suggestions I have implemented the following solution. Instead of creating my tiles and drawing them every loop, I have changed it to where I define my GameBoard tiles initially in GameView and store them to an ArrayList...

```
//Within GameBoard class
public static void makeGameBoard() {
    tiles = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
            GameTile gameTile = new GameTile(new RectF(originX + i * tileSize + (20 * i),
                    originY + j * tileSize + (20 * j),
                    originX + (i + 1) * tileSize + (20 * i),
                    originY + (j + 1) * tileSize + (20 * j)), Color.DKGRAY);
            tiles.add(gameTile);

        }
    }
}
```

I then use a separate method to draw them from this ArrayList in draw...

```
//Within GameBoard class
public static void drawGameBoard(Canvas canvas) {
    for (int i = 0; i < tiles.size(); i++) {
        tiles.get(i).draw(canvas);
    }
}
```

Finally, to handle the interactions between the board's gameTiles and the player's gamePiece I simply check if the Point at the center of the gamePiece is within any of the gameBoard's gameTiles in the tiles ArrayList with RectF's built in .contains method.

```
//Within GameBoard class
public static void doesTileInteract(Point gamePiecePoint) {
    for (int i = 0; i < tiles.size(); i++) {
        if (tiles.get(i).getRectangle().contains(gamePiecePoint.x, gamePiecePoint.y)) {
            System.out.println("The tiles are interacting!");
        }
    }
}
```

Which is called in the onTouchEvent method.

```
//Within GameView class
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

    switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: //player pressing down
            wasClicked = gamePiece.getRectangle().contains((int) event.getX(), (int) event.getY());

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: //player moving their finger
            if (wasClicked) {
                gamePiecePoint.set((int) event.getX(), (int) event.getY() - 100);
            }
            GameBoard.doesTileInteract(gamePiecePoint);
    }
    return true;
    //return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}
```

Thanks so much to @Mike M. for all his suggestions!! I really appreciate the help.